# XSL template match everything except something

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a xsl with a snippet that looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="group">
<xsl:element name="group">
<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
```

However, I need it to copy all groups except those with the typevalue "RECORD". How do I do this? I can use both XSL 1.0 and 2.0, with 1.0 preferred. The source file contains several thousand groups, with 4-5 different typevalues. I want the code to select only those groups without the typevalue RECORD.

Here's a example group that should be filtered away:

```
<group recstatus="1">
    <sourcedid>
      <source>system_owner_28f57240-5e2b-44af-8e62-fbf9aa6b6165</source>
      <id>basic_groups_69782a81-042d-4717-b9e4-18abacb306b7</id>
    </sourcedid>
    <grouptype>
      <scheme>Unique</scheme>
      <typevalue level="0">RECORD</typevalue>
    </grouptype>
    <description>
      <short>Ipsum dipsum</short>
    </description>
    <relationship>
      <sourcedid>
        <source>system_owner_28f57240-5e2b-44af-8e62-fbf9aa6b6165</source>
        <id>69782a81-042d-4717-b9e4-18abacb306b7</id>
      </sourcedid>
      <label>Ipsum dipsum</label>
    </relationship>
</group>
```

Many thanks for all and any help!

Comment: So which output do you want for that example input you have shown?

Comment: It would be better to do this filtering by applying templates selectively, not by restricting the match pattern. Otherwise the unmatched `group` will be handled by the default template.

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear. The source file contains several thousand groups, with 4-5 different typevalues. I want the code to select only those groups without the typevalue RECORD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//group[not(grouptype/typevalue[level = 0] = 'RECORD')]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

you copy those `group` elements not having that descendant `typevalue` being `RECORD`.

Or, if you want to use the identity transformation template to copy everything then reverse the condition to avoid copying the elements you want to eliminate with an empty template

```
<xsl:template match="group[grouptype/typevalue[level = 0] = 'RECORD']"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to do the trick. Unfortunately, the xml file also contains several thousand <person> and <membership> elements that I need to retain, and these are now being filtered away as well.

Comment: Well, next time consider to show a reduced but complete and minimal sample of XML input, XSLT you have, output you want and the one you get to illustrate the problem. I have edited the answer to show an alternative approach with a template not copying the elements you want to remove, it assumes you also put the identity transformation template in your code as a starting point to handle the rest.

Comment: I will, thank you. Your revised answer worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your question literally, the most direct XSLT representation of the requirement is to have two template rules:

```
<xsl:template match="*[everything()]" priority="10">
  ..
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[something()]" priority="20"/>
```

that is, a rule that matches "something" and does nothing, and a lower-priority rule that matches "everything" and does something.